# AirDrop svg file to my app

Tags: svg, airdrop

I want to develop an iOS app that can receive svg graphic files from mac by AirDrop. Now I encountered a problem, the file was always be tried to import to Photo app, see [Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIPxN.png), how can I let it choose my app that is expected to handle it